# immediateUpload / autoUpload with rich:fileupload

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

The upload doesnt start automatic when i choose a file. Still need to upload it manual by clicking the upload-button.

```
<rich:fileUpload ....
        immediateUpload="true">
```

Is there a way to make this work? 
Im using richfaces 4.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

1. First copy the fileupload.js in to your application and add the same in your page like below:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/js/fileupload.js"></script>
   ```
2. Second go to fileUpload.js and find a function called `__updateButtons` and update the first if which is checking the items length with the `this.__startUpload()`;

   like below.

   ```
   __updateButtons: function() {

   if (!this.loadableItem && this.list.children(".rf-fu-itm").size()) {

       if (this.items.length) {

           //this.uploadButton.css("display", "inline-block");

           this.__startUpload();// New - Added the immediate upload to work.

       } else {
   ```